# Audio TAG Not using MediaElement When Page is loaded through ajax

Tags: ajax

I am using APPL loaded to load all pages of the website.

One of the page is the blog read page, where the entire blog is been opened up for user preview. Some blog pages have audio tags in it where the WP audio player is showing up. If you open up this link http://tourworthy.com/tw21/?page_id=20&bID=17&bType=2 the audio player looks fine. but if you open up the same blog entry via http://tourworthy.com/tw21/?page_id=5751, then click "User blog" tab and go to page 2 of the listing and click the first blog (this is the same blog of which I have given the link earlier). Now you can notice, the audio player is not the same.

I have checked the source, if I load the entire website with the blog read page, the audio player is using MediaElement.js but when loaded from ajax it is not.

Is there a solution to this, so that MediaElement.js is been used even using ajax page load

A quick help will be appriciated